# Get text of dynamically generated TextBox controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++)
 {
      TextBox generatedField = new TextBox();
      generatedField.Text = "Please enter Field Report ID Here";
      generatedField.Width = 176;
      generatedField.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
      panel1.Controls.Add(generatedField);
      panel1.Show();
      pointY += 25;
}
```

After generating the TextBoxes, how can I find out what was typed into them?

Comment: Give the control a name: `generatedField.Name = "something";`, then you can reference it: `panel1.Controls["something"]...`

Comment: why downvote my question?

Comment: I didn't.  I tried helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `Name` of your controls, then you can access them by name this way:

**Create controls and assign Name:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++)
{
     TextBox generatedField = new TextBox();
     generatedField.Name = "someName_" + i.ToString();
     generatedField.Text = "Please enter Field Report ID Here";
     generatedField.Width = 176;
     generatedField.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);
     panel1.Controls.Add(generatedField);
     panel1.Show();
     pointY += 25;
}
```

**Find and Use controls:**

```
var txt = (TextBox)panel1.Controls["someName_1"];
MessageBox.Show(txt.Text);
```

**Some Notes:**

---

***Unique Names:*** Pay attention to generate unique names.

***Null Checking:*** You may want add null checking after `var txt = (TextBox)panel1.Controls["someName_1"];`

***Another Option:*** You can use `this.Controls.Find`
You can also use this code, that will return a `TextBox` with name of `someName_1`:

```
 var txt = this.Controls.Find("someName_1", true).Cast<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
```

***Handling Events:*** You can add `TextChanged` event
Another thing you may find useful, is adding `TextChanged` event when creating controls:

```
generatedField.TextChanged += generatedField_TextChanged;
```

This way, you should have this method in form:

```
void generatedField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = (TextBox)sender;
    // do what you need with txt.Text and other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm why not just keep track of what you created?

```
// somewhere else in your code, maybe when the form is created...
var MapOfMyBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
```

Then modify your code block like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++)
{
  TextBox generatedField = new TextBox();
  MapOfMyBoxes.Add("dontUseThisLiteralUseSomethingElse", generatedField);

  generatedField.Text = "Please enter Field Report ID Here";
  generatedField.Width = 176;
  generatedField.Location = new Point(pointX, pointY);

  panel1.Controls.Add(generatedField);
  panel1.Show();
  pointY += 25;
}
```

Later on you could refer back to your textbox:

```
  var message = MapOfMyBoxes["dontUseThisLiteralUseSomethingElse"].Text;
```

**Caveat**: remember to clean up the dictionary as these textboxes go out of scope/disposed, etc!

Comment: While `panel1.Controls` and `this.Controls` are available, I think using a dictionary makes no sense :)

Comment: You'd rather traverse the entire children tree? How would that be faster and more efficient?